# iPhone SDK, adding annotations to mapview through a 2nd thread, need to refresh mapview

Tags: objective-c, android-mapview

Im writing an iphone app that needs to display annotations depending on groups like "Petrol Stations","Restaurant" as user selects. I'm using MBProgressHUD and adding annotations is done in background by a 2nd thread everytime user clicks on a choice. The problem is the new annotations aren't displayed on the screen until I move the map around. Is there anyway to kind of "refresh" or "wake" the mapView to display new annotations immediately after I add them from another thread ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
You can create a method that adds the annotations to the mapView after you calculated the coordinates in the background you call.

```
[controller performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addingMethod) withObject:annotation waitUntilDone:NO]
```

Comment: Can you please explain more detailed. What does "Method" look like ? Thanks

Comment: I think I was wrong, you have to add the annotation in the main thread. MKMapView will take care of the rest. You can still calculate the coordinates in the background.